# How to smooth LSTM output

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to predict some time-series signal using a number of other time-series signals. For that purpose i'm using a LSTM network. The input signals are normalized and the same are the output signals. I'm using MSE loss, and implementing using tensorflow
The network give farely good prediction, but it is very noisy. I want to make it more smooth, as if a LPF filter was used on the LSTM output. 
The optimal solution for me is some parameter that i can change that will filter more/less frequencies from the LSTM output.

How can i do that? i was thinking about trying to constrain the loss function somehow?

Thanks

I tried adding a fully connected layers after the LSTM, batch normalization and single and multi-layer LSTM networks